# Hiding divs based on a selected radio button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm having an issue with radio buttons showing one div and hiding the rest. I have my code which I'll post below (tested and working in jsfiddle but not when I put it onto my page).

To give you an idea of what I'm after, I am making a registration page. The radio buttons will control a div that has the form placed inside it, so radio 1 checked, div 1 is selected, and the rest hidden and so on.

Here's my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#accountchoice').change(function() {
if ($('#personalfan').attr('checked')) {
    $('#personalfan1').show();
    $('#soloartist1').hide();
    $('#band1').hide();
    $('#venue1').hide();
    $('#business1').hide();
    $('#service1').hide();
} else if ($('#soloartist').attr('checked')) {
    $('#soloartist1').show();
    $('#personalfan1').hide();
    $('#band1').hide();
    $('#venue1').hide();
    $('#business1').hide();
    $('#service1').hide();
} else if ($('#band').attr('checked')) {
    $('#band1').show();
    $('#personalfan1').hide();
    $('#soloartist1').hide();
    $('#venue1').hide();
    $('#business1').hide();
    $('#service1').hide();
} else if ($('#venue').attr('checked')) {
    $('#venue1').show();
    $('#personalfan1').hide();
    $('#soloartist1').hide();
    $('#band1').hide();
    $('#business1').hide();
    $('#service1').hide();
} else if ($('#business').attr('checked')) {
    $('#business1').show();
    $('#personalfan1').hide();
    $('#soloartist1').hide();
    $('#band1').hide();
    $('#venue1').hide();
    $('#service1').hide();
} else if ($('#service').attr('checked')) {
    $('#service1').show();
    $('#personalfan1').hide();
    $('#soloartist1').hide();
    $('#band1').hide();
    $('#venue1').hide();
    $('#business1').hide();


 }
 });
 </script>
```

and here's the HTML

```
 <body>
 <?php include_once "header_template.php"; ?>
   <div id="signupwrapper">
 <div id="signupinner">

       <h3 align="left"> GETSCENE REGISTRATION ! </h3>
       <hr />

    <div id="signup" style="border:thin; border-color:#666">
    <h4 align="left">Please Choose One of The Following Account Types</h4>
        <div id="accountswrapper">
  <form id="accountchoice" name="accountchoice" method="post" action="">

  <label for="radio">personal/fan</label>   
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="personalfan" value="radio1" checked="checked" />

  <label for="radio2">Solo artist</label>   
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="soloartist" value="radio2" />

  <label for="radio3">band</label>               
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="band" value="radio3" />

  <label for="radio4">venue</label>   
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="venue" value="radio4" />

  <label for="radio5">business</label>   
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="business" value="radio5" />

  <label for="radio6">service</label>   
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="service" value="radio6" />
  </form>  

  <hr />
  <div id="personalfan1">1</div>
  <div id="soloartist1">2</div>
  <div id="band1">3</div>
  <div id="venue1">4</div>
  <div id="business1">5</div>
  <div id="service1">6</div>
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php include_once "footer_template.php"; ?>
</body>
```

Any help here will be really appreciated as I've been banging my head against this for hours.

Comment: I have tested with your code, as you mentioned when i click on first radio button the first div is visible and others are hidden.It is working for me.Can you explain me what is your issue?.

Answer (score 4):

This script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#accountchoice').change(function() {
```

Will only work if it's at the **end** of your body tag.  If it's in the head, it won't do anything, since the dom won't be ready when the script runs.

The easiest way to fix this is to put this code into a document.ready handler:

```
$(function() {
    //this will run when the dom is ready
    $('#accountchoice').change(function() {
});
```

---

You should be able to trim this code down and do it all in one shot by looking at the radio that's checked

```
var allDivs = ['venue1', 'personalfan1', 'soloartist1', 'band1', 'business1', 'service1'];

var radio = $("input[type='radio']:checked");
if (radio.length === 0)
    return;
$('#' + allDivs.join(',#')).hide();
$("div#" + radio[0].id + "1").show();
```

Comment: Does jQuery allow using .change() on a form?

Comment: @Walkerneo - I'm not sure, but if not, there are easy workarounds: `$("input", "#formId").change(function() { ...`

Comment: Also, these are radios not checkboxes.

Comment: And the top part could be `$('body').on('change','input[name="radio"]',function() {`

Comment: ok fantastic guys, finally working as adam suggested. only issue i have now is that when i first load the page i have all 6 divs showing. is there an easy way of just having the default set a the first radio for page load?

Comment: @mike - there are lots of ways you could do that.  I would just put that code above into a function, called, say, `adjustDivsFromRadio`, then render your page with the right radio checked, then in your documnet.ready just call `adjustDivsFromRadio()`

Answer (score 1):

You could restructure your HTML to make your life MUCH easier.

Here is an example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #account_types > div { display: none; }
</style>
<div id="signupwrapper">
    <div id="signupinner">
        <h3 align="left"> GETSCENE REGISTRATION ! </h3>
        <hr />
        <div id="signup" style="border:thin; border-color:#666">
            <h4 align="left">Please Choose One of The Following Account Types</h4>
            <div id="accountswrapper">
                <form id="accountchoice" name="accountchoice" method="post" action="">
                    <label for="personalfan">personal/fan</label>   
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="personalfan" value="radio1" checked="checked" />

                    <label for="soloartist">Solo artist</label>   
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="soloartist" value="radio2" />

                    <label for="band">band</label>               
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="band" value="radio3" />

                    <label for="venue">venue</label>   
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="venue" value="radio4" />

                    <label for="business">business</label>   
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="business" value="radio5" />

                    <label for="service">service</label>   
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="service" value="radio6" />
                </form>  

                <hr />
                <div id="account_types">
                    <div class="personalfan">1</div>
                    <div class="soloartist">2</div>
                    <div class="band">3</div>
                    <div class="venue">4</div>
                    <div class="business">5</div>
                    <div class="service">6</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#accountchoice').change(function() {
            var divToShow = $(this).find('input:checked').attr('id');
            $('#account_types > div').each(function() {
                if($(this).hasClass(divToShow)) { $(this).show(); }
                else { $(this).hide();}
            });

        });

        $('#accountchoice').trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```

Now, if you'll take a note at the restructuring, you'll see a few things.  First, the Divs that contained the different account types are inside a holding Div.  You don't need to do that, but it makes it easier to isolate them.  You could just as easily have given them all a similar class to accomplish the same task.

Secondly, they now have class names that are the same as their associated input ID.  This makes it very easy to reference the exact one you are looking for, while still making it easy to touch the rest of them too.  So now you can loop through the array of these elements, show() the Div that goes along with the selected radio, and hide() the ones that aren't.  All in a few small steps.

This also makes it much easier to add new parts to your code.  Otherwise, if you added a new section, you'd have to edit each if() statement you made, adding the new section to make sure it shows and hides properly.

This is where you can see some of the power of the DOM.  Much simpler code, easier to maintain, and you can reuse it later on.

I also fixed the labels for you too.

Comment: tim this also works fantastic and really simplifies the code, as you can probably tell, im still learning js, also thanks for renaming and fixing the lables lol.  still, even with this the default personalfan div is hidden on page load so guessing i would still need to put the code into a function?

Comment: No, you can actually just do something as simple as,

    `$('#accountchoice').trigger('change');`

I've updated the example to show you where it would go.

Comment: tim and alex, thank you ever so much, all of you guys actually! my brain no longer feels like it doesnt fit inside my head lol. all sorted and working dandy, defo gonna give you guys a mention when the site goes live :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example, though it does require a little change to HTML to make it neat/easy to manage.

**HTML**

```
// Added class "choice" to the radio inputs
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="venue" class="choice" value="radio4" />
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="business" class="choice" value="radio5" />
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="service" class="choice" value="radio6" />

<div class="account_types">
    <div class="dynamic" id="venue1">
        4</div>
    <div class="dynamic" id="business1">
        5</div>
    <div class="dynamic" id="service1">
        6</div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('input.choice').click(function () {
    var eleToShow = this.id + "1";
    $('div', '.account_types').hide();
    $('#' + eleToShow).show();
});
```